# Visual Studio 2015 crashes when attempting to publish ASP.NET core Web Application

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I have an ASP.NET core 1.0 web application that builds fine.
When I attempt to publish the web app I get a modal that appears stating "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" and if I close the modal warning and click publish, Visual Studio crashes.

[image: Error Image]

[image: vs crash image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was a syntax error in my appsettings.json file. I was simply missing a comma. My suggestion is to check any of the *.json settings files for syntax errors.

IMO, the easiest way to view any warnings within said files is by using the *Error List* window.